# System.IO.Directory.GetFiles for specific file name

Tags: c#, getfiles

in my local file folder,contain files.
eg TB2.8.5_asd_asd and TB2.9.5_asd_asd. How can i do only get the file which the name start with TB2.6.5_

```
string[] dirs = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[@"LocalFolderPath"], "*" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LocalFilesExtension"]).Where(s => s.StartsWith("TB2.6.5_")).ToArray();
```

Comment: What does `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LocalFilesExtension"]` contain? Does it start with a `.`?

Comment: <add key="LocalFolderPath" value='C:\Users\RNKP74\Desktop\testfolder2' />
     
      <add key="LocalFilesExtension" value=' ' />

Comment: it start with path and extension

Comment: Your `LocalFilesExtension` looks empty, so you're filtering on `*` instead of `*.*`

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen how to get only a file name start  with TB2.6.5_? currently i able to get all the files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`Directory.GetFiles()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2(v=vs.110).aspx) method allows you to specify the search pattern as one of its input parameters. you can utilize that to complete your requirement. So the code will be like this:

```
string PathToDirectory=Path.Combine(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[@"LocalFolderPath"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[@"LocalFilesExtension"];
string searchPattern="TB2.6.5_*.*";
string[] dirs =  System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(PathToDirectory,searchPattern,SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).ToArray();
```

Change `SearchOption` to `AllDirectories` if you want to extend the search to sub-directories, You can change the searchPattern according to the requirement.

**Update as per your comment:** `Illegal characters in path`.

This will be depend on the value you are storing in the config. ie., `AppSettings["LocalFilesExtension"]` if there is `\\` used as path separator, then need not to include `@`  before i\since it will convert the `\\` to `\\\\` If There is only a single `\` in Config then use `@`

Comment: Illegal characters in path.

Comment: string PathToDirectory="ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[@'LocalFolderPath'], '*' + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings['LocalFilesExtension']";
                    string[] dirs = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(PathToDirectory, "TB2.6.5_*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToArray();

Comment: @Yeep: The reason for this will be the data you stored in the config, see the update notes

Comment: <add key="LocalFolderPath" value='C:\Users\RNKP74\Desktop\testfolder2' />

Comment: @Yeep : so use `string PathToDirectory=Path.Combine(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[@"LocalFolderPath"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[@"LocalFilesExtension"];`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the filter parameter to set it

[Directory.GetFiles(String, String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f(v=vs.110).aspx)

i.e.

```
"filename.exe" = filters for filename.exe
"filename.*" = filters all files with the name filename
"*filename*" = contains filename
```

Comment: string[] dirs = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("path", ".exe");